# Can you run a binary search on a list of strings with a substring comparison?

Tags: c#

The problem is I have a list of about 800,000 string elements, and trying to match a substring of the strings. Right, now I am doing it through an exhaustive search (brute force), but that is taking hours. I was hoping there would be a faster and more elegant method

```
namespace Sorting_Program_Ver1_1
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] tempStringArray; string[] dataStringArray; string[] dotdotStringArray;
        List<string> myList = new List<string>();
        List<string> twoDots = new List<string>();
        Console.WriteLine("Starting program - initialising variables");

        tempStringArray = File.ReadAllLines("C:\\datadomains");
        int count = 0;

        for (int a = 0; a < tempStringArray.Length - 1; a++)
        {
            if (tempStringArray[a].Length > 0)
            {
                myList.Add(tempStringArray[a]);
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Adding items to string list");

        for (int b = 0; b < myList.Count; b++)
        {
            for (int c = 0; c < myList[b].Length; c++)
            {
                if (myList[b][c] == '.')
                {
                    count++;
                }
            }
            if (count == 2)
            {
                twoDots.Add(myList[b]);
            }
            count = 0;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Sorting the list into 2");

        dotdotStringArray = twoDots.ToArray();
        System.IO.File.WriteAllLines("C:\\twoDots.txt", dotdotStringArray);

        Console.WriteLine("Starting the search...");
        for (int d = 0; d < twoDots.Count; d++)
        {
            for (int e = myList.Count - 1; e > 0; e--)
            {
                if (myList[e] == "")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Removing empty space...");
                    myList.RemoveAt(e);              
                }

                int start = myList[e].Length - twoDots[d].Length;
                if (start >= 0)
                {
                    if (twoDots[d] == myList[e].Substring(start, twoDots[d].Length))
                    {
                        if (twoDots[d] != twoDots[d])
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Removing...", myList[e]);
                            myList.RemoveAt(e);
                        }
                    }                       
                }
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Saving to file ...");
        dataStringArray = myList.ToArray();
        System.IO.File.WriteAllLines("C:\\myList.txt", dataStringArray);
        Console.WriteLine("Saved to file");
        Console.WriteLine("Exit program");
    }
}
```

}

Example:

```
mylist[0]= ".bob.com"
mylist[1]= ".steve.bob.com"
mylist[2]= ".steve.job.bob.com"
...
mylist[800000]= ".coffee.com"

substring=".bob.com"
```

I'm trying to look through the list and match the strings with substring and get rid of subdomains.
Is this more clear?

Comment: Hours? What is your memory footprint? Paging might be the issue...

Comment: I'm struggling to understand what your code is really trying to do. Could you give some examples of some of the strings that you're searching through, and the type of substrings that you're searching for?

Comment: There is a lot of methods to do it efficiently , binary search, dictionary, ABB, etc. but what do you mean with substring comparison exactly?

Comment: Your code can benefit from some refactoring in various ways. Could you briefly describe what it is supposed to do?

Comment: Have you checked [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3f90y839.aspx)

Comment: What are you trying to do with the `if (twoDots[d] != twoDots[d])` line?  Why would it not equal itself?

Comment: So, will it always, in fact, be a *suffix* search, and not a general substring search? If so, have you considered reversing all of the strings (both the list and the search value) so that you can perform a prefix search?

Comment: Sorry that was a old part of the code I've removed that

Comment: Could it be that [Logparser](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptcenter/dd919274.aspx) would make things a lot easier for you?

Answer (score 2):

Binary search cannot be an option here, because that implies that the entire tree itself is in a certain order (and ideally balanced). Since you want to do partial comparison, order is of no importance and hence binary search does not help.

You may want to look into the Boyer-Moore string search algorithm, which is very efficient, especially with long strings.

Check it out at http://www.akira.ruc.dk/~keld/teaching/algoritmedesign_f05/Artikler/09/Boyer77.pdf. If you just Google for "Boyer-Moore" you should also be able to find some interesting links, such as this chapter out of a book on algorithms: http://orion.lcg.ufrj.br/Dr.Dobbs/books/book5/chap10.htm.

There is also a more recent algorithm called Breslauer-Grossi-Mignosi (that you can find at http://www.stupros.com/site/postconcept/Breslauer-Grossi-Mignosi.pdf). I haven't studied that one yet, so I cannot comment on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can only perform a binary search if you are interested in complete equality of the strings, or if you are looking for substrings *that start at the beginning of the strings you are searching through*, which you are not, so no, you cannot use a Binary Search.

Comment: The list of strings is not mantioned like an ordered list, so binary search may be not an option in first place.

Comment: @Tigran You can always sort a list, if that were the only problem.  The point here is that it's impossible to do *even if the list is sorted*.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a *any* part of the string as a subset, you want to build is a Suffix Trie. Effectively there is no payload, but you build a Trie of all known suffixes of the entire text which can be done in a single O(n) traversal of the text. This takes up quite a bit more memory than just having a large string sitting in memory, but it is a very efficient way of storing the data related to the string. A search for a substring is then an O(m) operation against the trie (where m is the length of the substring you're searching for), which will be pretty darned quick.

If you just want to match whole words, you could also put all words into a `HashSet<string>`, perhaps using the constructor overload to ignore case, and then do O(1) checks for the given word existing.

Suffix Tree (the Trie variant would have no occurrence payload): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree

In all computing, the balance is efficiency/performance and memory. You will sacrifice memory for performance, or performance for memory savings, but it's rare to gain both at once. :)

Comment: @Hector210387 - the wikipedia link I gave shows an example and outlines the implementation. A little Googling past that and you'll see some other examples.